# Python cov_struct attribute for MixedLM

Tags: python, statsmodels

I would like to specify the cov_struct attribute when calling the method MixedLM (statsmodels package) but it doesn't work.

On the contrary, when specifying this parameter to the method GEE (statsmodels), it works!

More precisely :

```
sm.GEE.from_formula("Y ~ X1 + X2 - 1", data=data,groups=Xg, cov_struct=sm.genmod.cov_struct.Exchangeable()).fit()
```

works.

But

```
sm.MixedLM.from_formula("Y ~ X1 + X2 - 1", data=data,groups=Xg, cov_struct=sm.genmod.cov_struct.Exchangeable()).fit()
```

Does not Work

The error I get is :

> {AttributeError}'Exchangeable' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Also, I don t really understand the groups attribute.

Comment: MixedLM does not handle cov_struct yet. Your keyword cov_struct is put into the `**kwargs`  and treated as a data array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cov_struct is only for GEE.  If you want to specify the covariance structure in MixedLM use 're_formula'.

Note that GEE in statsmodels is much more mature than MixedLM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
By covariance structure you mean covariance matrix I suppose. And what about the "groups" attribute? Can I find a clear documentation somewhere?

Comment: Quite a few examples are linked to [this page](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/wiki/Examples).  Note in particular the Sitka growth example that uses a random slope.  MixedLM does not support time series style covariance structures like AR.  The covariance is defined implicitly through the random effects structure.